# conditional probability poisson and exponential

Tags: conditional-probability

Suppose X and Y are independent random variables having the
same Poisson distribution with parameter A, but where A is also random,
being exponentially distributed with parameter 0. What is the conditional
distribution for X given that X + Y = n?

I know I should reach binomial distribution but I can't.

Comment: Hint: first solve the problem for the case where $A$ is a (nonzero) constant.  Use the definition of conditional probability and have confidence that the algebra will be simple.

Answer (score 4):

**You can do this with no calculation.**

As explained (without calculation) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/261926/919, the union of two Poisson processes of rates $\lambda$ and $\mu$ is a Poisson process of rate $\lambda+\mu:$ just remove the colors from the points in the top picture and treat them all as coming from the same process, as shown in the bottom.

[image: Figure]

The reverse is true, too: given the $n$ gray points at the bottom realizing part of a Poisson process of rate $\nu,$ randomly and independently color them orange with probability $\lambda/(\lambda+\mu)$ and otherwise blue.  The recolored points obviously satisfy all the [criteria to be Poisson processes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/215253/919) (one for each color).

Consequently, *conditional on $n,$* $X$ (with parameter $\lambda$) is equivalent to randomly and independently coloring each of the $n$ points with probability $p = \lambda/(\lambda+\mu)$ (where $Y$ has parameter $\mu$).  That has a Binomial$(n,p)$ distribution (by definition); namely, for $k=0, 1, \ldots, n,$

$$\Pr(X=k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}.$$

In the case of the question, $\lambda=\mu$ and $p=1/2$ *no matter what value the common parameters $\lambda=\mu$ may have.*  Consequently, it doesn't matter what the distribution of that parameter might be: the answer doesn't vary.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "exponentially distributed with parameter 0" (to me that sounds like a uniform distribution maybe?). Let's just solve the more general case instead.

$$  P(x|A) = \frac{1}{x!}A^{x}e^{-A} $$
$$  P(y|A) = \frac{1}{y!}A^{y}e^{-A} $$
$$  P(A) = \lambda e^{-\lambda A} $$

where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers and $A$ and $\lambda$ are real. Let's define the variable $z=x+y$. We look for $P(x|z=n)$. Using Bayes theorem,

$$ P(x|z=n,A) = \frac{P(z=n|x,A)P(x|A)}{P(z=n|A)} $$

Let's find what the different terms are

$$1) \ \ \ P(z=n|x,A) = \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} P(z=n|x,y,A)P(y|A)  = \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \delta((x+y)-n)P(y|A) = P(y=n-x|A) = \frac{1}{(n-x)!}A^{n-x}e^{-A}, \ n \ge x$$

$$2) \ \ \  P(z=n|A) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} P(z=n|x,y,A)P(y|x,A)P(x|A)  = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \delta((x+y)-n)P(y|A)P(x|A)  = \sum_{y=0}^{n}P(y|A)P(x=n-y|A)  = \sum_{y=0}^{n}  \frac{1}{y!}A^{y}e^{-A} \frac{1}{(n-y)!}A^{n-y}e^{-A} = e^{-2A}A^{n}\sum_{y=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(n-y)!}\frac{1}{y!}$$

Note the change of limits in the sum over $y$. This is because the $\delta$ has a non-zero value only if $n-y \ge 0$. Putting all together we get

$$ P(x|z=n,A) = \frac{\frac{1}{(n-x)!}\frac{1}{x!}}{\sum_{y=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(n-y)!}\frac{1}{y!}} , \ n \ge x$$

Now we must take into account that $A$ is also a random variable. However, the result we found does actually not depend on $A$, so

$$ P(x|z=n) = \int_0^\infty P(x|z=n,A)P(A)dA = \frac{\frac{1}{(n-x)!}\frac{1}{x!}}{\sum_{y=0}^{n} \frac{1}{(n-y)!}\frac{1}{y!}}, \ n \ge x$$

**UPDATE:**
We can continue and show that the distribution is binomial. First, we write the final expression in terms of binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{x}=\frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}$,

$$ P(x|z=n) = \frac{\binom{n}{x}}{\sum_{y=0}^{n} \binom{n}{y}}, \ n \ge x$$

We can calculate the sum in the denominator using the binomial theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem),

$$ (a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}a^{n-k}b^k$$

For that, we consider the special case in which $a=b$, in which case the expression above reduces to

$$ 2^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}$$

and substituting it we arrive to the final result

$$ P(x|z=n) = \binom{n}{x}2^{-n}, \ n \ge x$$

which as you expected is a binomial distribution with parameter $p=1/2$. We arrive at this special case with $p=1/2$ because the Poisson distributions of $x$ and $y$ share the same value of the parameter $A$. In the case that they were different, I expect that we would arrive to a binomial with $p=A_{x}/(A_{x}+A_{y})$, as pointed out by @whuber.

Comment: Could you help us make sense of the infinite sum in the denominator of your answer?

Comment: Fixed. See edit.