Substraction of Poisson and Binomail is Poisson, but sum is not?
Dear Stack Exchange community,
Assume we have two variables $N$ and $k$ such that $N \sim \text{Poiss}(\mu)$ and $k \sim \text{Binom}(n=N, p)$. Note that the number of trials in $k$ equals to $N$. Doing a toy Monte-Carlo experiment I found that
$N_{-} = N - k$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\mu(1-p)$, while
$N_{+} = N + k$ does not follows Poisson distribution with parameter $\mu(1+p)$.
I was puzzled by this as I was expecting that the Poisson distribution would hold for both $N_{-}$ and $N_{+}$, so I am curious: can anyone explain this? and event better, could you provide a formal proof of why this holds? It was a long time since my last formal course in statistics and I am a little bit rusted with the on-paper calculations.
Thank you in advance.

The illustration of "thinning" a Poisson process at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/429589/919 says it all.  A "formal proof" would just be the calculation that underpins this intuition. // One way to see why $N_+$ shouldn't be Poisson is to contemplate the case where $p\approx 1:$ the sum will strongly favor outcomes that are even integers, which no Poisson variable can do, because they are all unimodal.  (It's instructive to consider why this argument does not hold for $N_-.$)

Here's an R simulation to illustrate the point about $N_+:$ x <- rpois(1e4, 5); y <- x + rbinom(length(x), x, 0.9); p <- table(y); plot(as.numeric(names(p)), p)

To accord with standard conventions for random variables, I'm going to use $K$ (upper-case instead of lower case) to denote the random variable from the binomial distribution.
It is simple to derive the mass function for the distributions of these two random variables using the law of total probability.  This yields the following results:
$$\begin{align}
p_{N_-}(n_-)
&= \mathbb{P}(N_- = n_-) \\[16pt]
&= \sum_{n} \mathbb{P}(N_- = n_-| N=n) \cdot \mathbb{P}(N=n) \\[8pt]
&= \sum_{n} \mathbb{P}(N-K = n_-| N=n) \cdot \mathbb{P}(N=n) \\[8pt]
&= \sum_{n} \mathbb{P}(K = n-n_-| N=n) \cdot \mathbb{P}(N=n) \\[8pt]
&= \sum_{n} \text{Bin}(n-n_-|n,p) \cdot \text{Pois}(n|\mu) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{n=n_-}^\infty {n \choose n-n_-} p^{n-n_-}(1-p)^{n_-} \cdot \frac{\mu^n e^{-\mu}}{n!} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{(\mu (1-p))^{n_-} e^{-\mu(1-p)}}{n_-!} \sum_{n=n_-}^\infty \frac{(\mu p)^{n-n_-} e^{-\mu p}}{(n-n_-)!} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{(\mu (1-p))^{n_-} e^{-\mu(1-p)}}{n_-!} \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{(\mu p)^{r} e^{-\mu p}}{r!} \\[6pt]
&= \text{Pois}(n_-|\mu (1-p)) \sum_{r=0}^\infty \text{Pois}(r|\mu p) \\[12pt]
&= \text{Pois}(n_-|\mu (1-p)), \\[24pt]
p_{N_+}(n_+)
&= \mathbb{P}(N_+ = n_+) \\[16pt]
&= \sum_{n} \mathbb{P}(N_+ = n_+| N=n) \cdot \mathbb{P}(N=n) \\[8pt]
&= \sum_{n} \mathbb{P}(N+K = n_+| N=n) \cdot \mathbb{P}(N=n) \\[8pt]
&= \sum_{n} \mathbb{P}(K = n_+-n| N=n) \cdot \mathbb{P}(N=n) \\[8pt]
&= \sum_{n} \text{Bin}(n_+-n|n,p) \cdot \text{Pois}(n|\mu) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{n= \lceil n_+/2 \rceil}^{n_+} {n \choose n_+-n} p^{n_+-n}(1-p)^{2n-n_+} \cdot \frac{\mu^n e^{-\mu}}{n!} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{n= \lceil n_+/2 \rceil}^{n_+} \frac{p^{n_+-n}(1-p)^{2n-n_+} \mu^n e^{-\mu}}{(n_+-n)! (2n-n_+)!}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
As can be seen, in the first case we confirm that $N_- \sim \text{Pois}(\mu (1-p))$ but in the second case we get a more complicated result that is not a common distributional family.

You are correct at the end, of course, but it would be nice to prove that this complicated expression does not simplify to a Poisson distribution.  One straightforward method is to exhibit multiple modes, as I suggest in a comment to the question.  You can always do this by choosing sufficiently large $p;$ I believe $p\gt 1 - 1/(\mu+1)$ will always work (but is not, by any means, a lower bound).
