Expected value of iid squared conditioned on sum
I would be interested in finding the value of the following expression:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_k^2\mid S_N]$$
where $X_k$ are iid random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_k]=\mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X_k]=\sigma^2$, $N$ is a deterministic constant and:
$$S_N=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$$
I tried to find it by using that
$$\mathbb{E}[S_N^2]=N\mathbb{E}[X_k^2 \mid S_N]+N(N-1)\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j\mid S_N]$$
with $i\neq j$. Nevertheless, even if the different $X_k$ are independent, they do not necessarily satisfy $\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j\mid S_N]=\mathbb{E}[X_i\mid S_N]^2$
Edit: Another approach I tried was using the fact that
$$\mathbb{E}[X_k^2\mid S_N] = \text{Var}(X_k\mid S_N) - \mathbb{E}[X_k\mid S_N]^2$$
The second term of the sum can easily be shown to be $S_N^2/N^2$. Nevertheless, the conditional variance is still not easy for me to crack. I tried relating $\text{Var}(X_k\mid S_N)$ to $\text{Cov}(X_k, S_N) = \sigma^2$ with no success.

You might want to start by looking at specific distributions.  For example, $\mathbb{E}[X_k^2|S_N]=\frac{(N-1) N \sigma ^2+S_N^2}{N^2}$ when $X_k \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Your equation $\mathbb{E}[S_N^2]=N\mathbb{E}[X_k^2 \mid S_N]+N(N-1)\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j\mid S_N]$ has problems.  There is no justification or rationale for including $\mid S_N$ on the righthand side.  The equation is essentially correct if you remove that resulting in $\mathbb{E}[S_N^2]=N\mathbb{E}[X_k^2]+N(N-1)\mathbb{E}[X_i X_j]$.  Again, consider a specific distribution.  For a normal distribution $X_1$ and $S_N$ are distributed as a bivariate normal.

the answer is $\sigma^2+\mu^2$, because $S_N$ has no impact on $X_k^2$

@Aksakal $X_k$ and $S_N=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ (with $1\leq k \leq N$) are not independent so the expectation of $X_k^2$ given $S_N=s$ is not $\sigma^2+\mu^2$ (unless $s=\pm\sqrt{\mu ^2 n^2+n\sigma ^2}$ when $X_k\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$).

@JimB if OP was looking for a function of $X_k$ I'd agree, but individual $X_k$ have nothing to do with the sum

@Aksakal We are certainly reading the question differently.  To me the question screams "conditional expectation" rather than "unconditional expectation."

@JimB, no, I'm talking about conditional. I might be wrong but I dont see an argument to why I'm wrong yet

@Aksakal Isn't the following link a discrete random variable answer to the OP's question?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84098/conditional-distribution-of-poisson-variables-given-sum-x-i.

@JimB, I dont think so, because that link talks about the joint probability of variables. OP is asking about marginals

I suspect the only symbolic results you'll be able to find involve those distributions whose sum of iid random variables follow the same family of distributions.  That is certainly the case for normal and gamma distributions.
Rather than show a step-by-step calculus approach, I'm going to just give handwaving arguments and Mathematica commands and I've slightly differed from your notation.  You can fill in details if desired.
Normal distributions
If $X_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $Y=\sum_{i=2}^n X_k$ has a normal distribution with mean $(n-1)\mu$ and variance $(n-1)\sigma^2$.  $X_1$ and $S_n=X_1+Y$ have a bivariate normal distribution with mean vector $(\mu, n\mu)$ and covariance matrix
$$\Sigma=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sigma ^2 & \sigma ^2 \\
 \sigma ^2 & n \sigma ^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
The conditional density of $X_1$ given $S_n=s$ is found by dividing the joint density of $(X_1, S_n))$ by the marginal density of $S_n$.  One then integrates $x_1^2$ times the conditional density over values of $x_1$.
Joint distribution of $X_1$ and $S_n$.
dist = TransformedDistribution[{x1, x1 + x2n},
   {x1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ],
    x2n \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[(n - 1) μ, σ Sqrt[n - 1]]}];

(* PDF's of joint and marginal distributions *)
pdfx1S = PDF[dist, {x1, s}]

$$\frac{\exp \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{(\text{x1}-\mu ) (n \text{x1}-s)}{(n-1) \sigma ^2}-\frac{(-\mu -\mu  (n-1)+s) (\mu -\mu  n+s-\text{x1})}{(n-1) \sigma ^2}\right)\right)}{2 \pi  \sqrt{n \sigma ^4-\sigma ^4}}$$
pdfs = Simplify[PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 2], s], Assumptions -> s > 0]

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{(s-\mu  n)^2}{2 n \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{n \sigma ^2}}$$
(* Find conditional expectation by integrating *)
Integrate[x1^2  pdfx1S/pdfs, {x1, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> {σ > 0, n > 1}]

$$\frac{(n-1) n \sigma ^2+s^2}{n^2}$$
Gamma distributions
If $X_i \sim \Gamma(k, \theta)$, then $Y=\sum_{i=2}^n X_i$ has a gamma distribution with parameters $(n-1)k$ and $\theta$.  We follow the same approach as above.
Joint distribution of $X_1$ and $S_n=X_1+Y$.
dist = TransformedDistribution[{x1, x1 + x2n},
   {x1 \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[k, θ],
    x2n \[Distributed] GammaDistribution[(n - 1) k, θ]}];

(* PDF's of joint and marginal distributions *)
pdfx1S = Simplify[PDF[dist, {x1, s}] // PiecewiseExpand, Assumptions -> {s > x1 > 0}]

$$\frac{\text{x1}^{k-1} e^{-\frac{s}{\theta }} \theta ^{-k n} (s-\text{x1})^{k (n-1)-1}}{\Gamma (k) \Gamma (k (n-1))}$$
pdfs = Simplify[PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 2], s], Assumptions -> s > 0]

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{s}{\theta }} \theta ^{-k n} s^{k n-1}}{\Gamma (k n)}$$
(* Find conditional expectation by integrating *)
Integrate[x1^2  pdfx1S/pdfs, {x1, 0, s}, Assumptions -> {s > 0, k > 0, n > 1}]

$$\frac{(k+1) s^2}{n (k n+1)}$$
Conclusion
In short, the condition expectation depends on the common distribution and it is unlikely to obtain a symbolic solution for very many distribution families.  It might seem odd that for the normal the conditional expectation is not a function of $\mu$ and for the gamma distribution the conditional expectation is not a function of $\theta$.

Similar approaches work for Possion, Binomial, and Negative binomial distributions.  I'll add those in the next few days (unless someone else wants to do that).
